# On Reflexive Banach Spaces

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, banach-spaces

My Functional Analysis lecturer gave me a topic for my assignment, the title is "**On Reflexive Banach Spaces"**. I am a looking for several good references to start my work, that is why I brought this question here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Benjamin: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: What is your assignment?

Comment: Maybe you could state briefly what you already know on reflexive spaces and what sources you already consulted. Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space

Comment: @mixedmath: Reflexive Banach Spaces.

Comment: @Hassan: I got that part. What about them?

Comment: @mixedmath: I have to write everything that is possible about Reflexive Banach spaces.

Comment: @Hassan: Then I recommend to you to say goodbye to your friends and family and invest in a library. There is an extensive literature on reflexive Banach spaces, and the subject is not dead. So I suppose you should also work on getting a PhD, in functional analysis of course, and coming up with some good, new results.

Comment: @mixedmath: This is the first time to hear this. But, I believe in what you said. I am only interested in having a background about the topic. That is all!

Answer (score 2):

Haim Breziz's *Functional Analysis, Sobolov Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations* chapter 3 is a good source for some some results about the weak topology and weak compactness in reflexive Banach Spaces. You may also want to show that Hilbert Space, particular $\ell^p$ and $L^p$ spaces, and Sobolev spaces are reflexive.

Comment: I will like to know where to find those result you mention.

Comment: There is an entire section on Reflective Banach Spaces in the book. Take a look in the index for some of the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Functional Analysis by Springer.

Obvious maths book is obvious

But really, it's a good starting book

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Adam.